# PythonのTensorflow-gpuのプロセッサ複数指定について

Tags: python, tensorflow, 深層学習, keras, gpu

PythonにてTensorflow-gpuを導入しており、複数のGPUで同時に計算させたいと思っています。

`keras.utils.training_utils` の `multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=gpu_count)` を実行することで、複数のGPUで計算できることを確認しました。

次に、具体的に使用するGPUを指定したいと考えています。
GPUを1つしか指定しない場合は、以下のコードで使用するGPUを指定できると思います。

```
with tf.device("/gpu:●"):
```

もし今回、3つ以上のGPUの中から、特定の2つのGPUを並列で使用したい場合、どのように記述すればよいのでしょうか？
例えば、gpu:0～3まで存在し、プログラムのある部分で、gpu:0,3のみを用いたいとき

```
with tf.device( [ "/gpu:0", "/gpu:3"]):
```

のようにしたいです。(上記はイメージで、このコードは上手くいきません)
このように、複数のGPUを具体的に指定することは可能なのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

リファレンスを見るとforループで設定する例が載っていました。

[Using multiple GPUs - TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#using_multiple_gpus)

```
# Creates a graph.
c = []
for d in ['/device:GPU:2', '/device:GPU:3']:
  with tf.device(d):
  ...
```